# Approximate the Function for a Family of Curves based on Linear Regression

Tags: r, linear-regression, curve

R:
`df` looks like this (`x = a, y = b, group = c`):

```
  a      b      c
-------------------
-2.1    1203    5
 1.4    1103    10
-2.1    1203    5
..       ..    ..
```

I created a scatterplot with around 10 linear regression lines (ggplot2/geom_smooth) from this `df`, for each group in `c`(e.g. 5, 10). These have all different *slopes* and *y-intersects*

Is there any way I can **approximate** the function for the **family of curves** for these  linear regression lines in R and display it with custom parameters in a new plot(ggplot2)?

---

edit:

Here is the `dput(df)`: (will remove it again later)

```
structure(list(X = 1:102, a = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "219.399.914.550.781", 
"987", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1320", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "144.595.013.427.734", 
"176.470.013.427.734", "167.919.995.117.188", "125.239.242.553.711", 
"247.582.397.460.938", "173.550.708.007.812", "149.010.693.359.375", 
"908", "638.5", "81.173.999.023.438", "1472", "120.632.000.732.422", 
"2028", "154.019.999.694.824", "785.5", "118.188.000.488.281", 
"149.930.010.986.328", "-712", "-2100", "1628", "925", "1161", 
"516", "64.840.002.441.406", "426.5", "106.810.998.535.156", 
"92.175.994.873.047", "648.5", "125.379.998.779.297", "1120", 
"821", "795", "129.179.998.779.297", "137.460.000.610.352", "127.231.660.461.426", 
"148.579.998.779.297", "115.440.997.314.453", "4.482.857.905.469", 
"1163", "97.440.002.441.406", "130.298.852.539.062", "195.956.491.088.867", 
"504.998.779.296.989", "1043", "228.998.406.982.422", "128.374.566.650.391", 
"153.219.995.117.188", "111.604.742.431.641", "108.100.006.103.516", 
"1364.5", "102.669.999.694.824", "141.820.001.220.703", "83.124.743.652.344", 
"93.209.649.658.203", "149.629.656.982.422", "150.215.002.441.406", 
"161.379.998.779.297", "41.129.998.779.297", "91.320.001.220.703", 
"83.047.998.046.875", "1144.5", "104.020.001.220.703", "171.528.002.929.688", 
"1519", "123.510.003.662.109", "106.240.002.441.406", "145.934.997.558.594", 
"177.939.999.389.648", "195.360.003.662.109", "164.140.002.441.406", 
"113.640.002.441.406", "146.676.000.976.562", "1.769.916.015.625", 
"53.389.654.541.016", "685.018.981.933.594"), c = c(88L, 88L, 
88L, 88L, NA, 88L, 88L, 88L, NA, NA, NA, 86L, 86L, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 90L, 88L, 88L, 88L, 
88L, 88L, 88L, 88L, 88L, 88L, 88L, 88L, 86L, 88L, 88L, 88L, 84L, 
84L, 84L, 84L, 86L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 
82L, 82L, 84L, 82L, 82L, 84L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 
82L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 80L, 80L, 
80L, 80L, 80L, 82L, 84L, 82L, 82L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L), c_null = c(88L, 88L, 88L, 88L, 
0L, 88L, 88L, 88L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 86L, 86L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 90L, 88L, 88L, 88L, 88L, 
88L, 88L, 88L, 88L, 88L, 88L, 88L, 86L, 88L, 88L, 88L, 84L, 84L, 
84L, 84L, 86L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 82L, 
82L, 84L, 82L, 82L, 84L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 
82L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
80L, 80L, 82L, 84L, 82L, 82L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L), c_orig = c("88.000.096.643.065", "88.000.096.643.065", 
"88.000.096.643.065", "0", "874.979.654.044.919", "873.618.932.305.081", 
"869.990.179.502.541", "0", "0", "0", "861.825.503", "861.825.503", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "899.000.015.258.789", "87.5", "880.999.984.741.211", "88", 
"879.000.015.258.789", "87", "869.000.015.258.789", "87", "868.000.030.517.578", 
"878.000.030.517.578", "876.999.969.482.422", "865.999.984.741.211", 
"861.999.969.482.422", "870.999.984.741.211", "869.000.015.258.789", 
"865.999.984.741.211", "871.999.969.482.422", "841.999.969.482.422", 
"84.5", "840.999.984.741.211", "845.999.984.741.211", "843.000.030.517.578", 
"841.999.969.482.422", "83", "834.000.015.258.789", "83", "825.999.984.741.211", 
"834.000.015.258.789", "831.999.969.482.422", "826.999.969.482.422", 
"823.000.030.517.578", "821.999.969.482.422", "825.999.984.741.211", 
"821.999.969.482.422", "82", "825.999.984.741.211", "816.999.969.482.422", 
"814.000.015.258.789", "81", "819.000.015.258.789", "816.999.969.482.422", 
"81.5", "821.999.969.482.422", "811.999.969.482.422", "814.000.015.258.789", 
"813.000.030.517.578", "808.000.030.517.578", "815.999.984.741.211", 
"818.000.030.517.578", "814.000.015.258.789", "814.000.015.258.789", 
"809.000.015.258.789", "809.000.015.258.789", "805.999.984.741.211", 
"801.999.969.482.422", "796.999.969.482.422", "801.999.969.482.422", 
"803.000.030.517.578", "804.000.015.258.789", "811.999.969.482.422", 
"825.999.984.741.211", "82.5", "819.000.015.258.789", "804.000.015.258.789", 
"795.999.984.741.211", "804.000.015.258.789", "80", "801.999.969.482.422", 
"798.000.030.517.578", "80", "80", "795.999.984.741.211", "800.999.984.741.211", 
"799.000.015.258.789", "791.999.969.482.422", "791.999.969.482.422"
), b = c("0", "0", "0", NA, NA, "-0.136072173983791", "-0.362875280254002", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, "0", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "-240.000.152.587.891", "0.599998474121094", 
"-0.0999984741210938", "-0.0999984741210938", "-0.900001525878906", 
"-0.0999984741210938", "0.0999984741210938", "-0.199996948242202", 
"1", "-0.100006103515597", "-109.999.847.412.111", "-0.400001525878892", 
"0.900001525878892", "-0.199996948242188", "-0.300003051757812", 
"0.599998474121108", "0.5", "0.300003051757798", "-0.400001525878906", 
"0.5", "-0.299995422363295", "-0.100006103515597", "-11.999.969.482.422", 
"0.400001525878906", "-0.400001525878906", "-0.400001525878906", 
"0.800003051757812", "-0.200004577636705", "-0.5", "-0.399993896484403", 
"-0.100006103515597", "0.400001525878892", "-0.400001525878892", 
"-0.199996948242202", "0.599998474121094", "-0.900001525878892", 
"-0.299995422363295", "-0.400001525878906", "0.900001525878906", 
"-0.200004577636705", "-0.199996948242202", "0.699996948242202", 
"-1", "0.200004577636705", "-0.099998474121108", "-0.5", "0.799995422363295", 
"0.200004577636705", "-0.400001525878892", "0", "-0.5", "0", 
"-0.300003051757812", "-0.400001525878892", "-0.5", "0.5", "0.100006103515597", 
"0.099998474121108", "0.799995422363295", "140.000.152.587.889", 
"-0.0999984741210938", "-0.599998474121094", "-1.5", "-0.800003051757812", 
"0.800003051757812", "-0.400001525878906", "0.199996948242202", 
"-0.399993896484403", "0.199996948242202", "0", "-0.400001525878906", 
"0.5", "-0.199996948242188", "-0.700004577636705", NA), b_null = c("0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "-0.136072173983791", "-0.362875280254002", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "-240.000.152.587.891", "0.599998474121094", 
"-0.0999984741210938", "-0.0999984741210938", "-0.900001525878906", 
"-0.0999984741210938", "0.0999984741210938", "-0.199996948242202", 
"1", "-0.100006103515597", "-109.999.847.412.111", "-0.400001525878892", 
"0.900001525878892", "-0.199996948242188", "-0.300003051757812", 
"0.599998474121108", "0.5", "0.300003051757798", "-0.400001525878906", 
"0.5", "-0.299995422363295", "-0.100006103515597", "-11.999.969.482.422", 
"0.400001525878906", "-0.400001525878906", "-0.400001525878906", 
"0.800003051757812", "-0.200004577636705", "-0.5", "-0.399993896484403", 
"-0.100006103515597", "0.400001525878892", "-0.400001525878892", 
"-0.199996948242202", "0.599998474121094", "-0.900001525878892", 
"-0.299995422363295", "-0.400001525878906", "0.900001525878906", 
"-0.200004577636705", "-0.199996948242202", "0.699996948242202", 
"-1", "0.200004577636705", "-0.099998474121108", "-0.5", "0.799995422363295", 
"0.200004577636705", "-0.400001525878892", "0", "-0.5", "0", 
"-0.300003051757812", "-0.400001525878892", "-0.5", "0.5", "0.100006103515597", 
"0.099998474121108", "0.799995422363295", "140.000.152.587.889", 
"-0.0999984741210938", "-0.599998474121094", "-1.5", "-0.800003051757812", 
"0.800003051757812", "-0.400001525878906", "0.199996948242202", 
"-0.399993896484403", "0.199996948242202", "0", "-0.400001525878906", 
"0.5", "-0.199996948242188", "-0.700004577636705", "0")), .Names = c("X", 
"a", "c", "c_null", "c_orig", "b", "b_null"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-102L))
```

And I have just plotted it with ggplot2:

```
ggplot(aes(x = a, y = b, group = c), data = Health, na.rm = TRUE) + 
  geom_point(aes(color = c, size = factor(c)), alpha=0.3) +
  scale_color_distiller(palette="YlGnBu", na.value="white") +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", aes(group = factor(c), color = c), se = F)
```

And now I want to approximate the family of curves for all the `geom_smooth` lines to predict in another plot different scenarios with other parameters!

Comment: Yes. Please provide sample data (paste into your question the output of `dput(data.sample)`) and the code you've run already and we can show you how.

Comment: Thanks. For future reference, it's better to provide a small data sample that illustrates your problem, rather than a large data set.

Comment: Ok, I will delete it later so other ppl. with the same question can read it more easily.

Comment: The data frame you posted has just one column of character data rather than multiple of columns of data that match the column names in your code. Please fix.

Comment: Done, sorry was an input mistake. Please tell me how to set it to code formatting all at once ;) Sry!

Comment: Highlight the entire code section and then click the `{}` at the top of the question window.

Comment: Thanks, also corrected a typo in the ggplot (GG -> c). Hope someone can help me here.

Comment: `a` and `b` are character variables in the data you posted.

Comment: But it does work for me like this? How to change it in R?

Comment: Yes, that data produces a plot, but the "numbers" it's plotting are the underlying factor codes, rather than actual data values. Take a look at the data you posted and see if it matches the data you're plotting with in your R session.

Comment: It is numeric in my file, plots and values are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple example of how to create and plot the prediction model.

First, let's create some fake data:

```
## Fake data
set.seed(595)
a = runif(50, 0, 100)
c = runif(50, 0, 100)

# Add equation for b in terms of a and c
dat = data.frame(a,c, b = 2*a + 3*c + 10 + rnorm(50, 0, 20))
```

Now, to predict `b`, from `a` and `c` we need a regression model:

```
## Regression model
m1 = lm(b ~ a + c, data=dat)
```

Here's a summary of that model:

```
summary(m1)
```

> ```
> Call:
>   lm(formula = b ~ a + c, data = dat)
>
> Residuals:
>   Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
> -63.169 -10.364   0.385  12.959  53.623 
>
> Coefficients:
>   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
> (Intercept) -3.63897    9.07948  -0.401     0.69    
> a            2.19203    0.09701  22.595   <2e-16 ***
> c            3.00188    0.11356  26.435   <2e-16 ***
> ---
> Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
>
> Residual standard error: 20.58 on 47 degrees of freedom
> Multiple R-squared:  0.9565,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.9547 
> F-statistic:   517 on 2 and 47 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
> ```

To plot the model predictions, let's create a data frame of those predictions. We'll predict `b` for four values of `c`.

```
## Predict b for various values of c and the entire range of a values
newdat = expand.grid(a=0:100, c=c(5,20,80,95))
newdat = data.frame(newdat, b_pred=predict(m1, newdata=newdat))
```

Now plot the data and the four predictions from the model:

```
# Plot points for b vs. a and then show prediction lines for various values of c.
ggplot(dat, aes(a, b)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(data=newdat, aes(a, b_pred, color=factor(c))) +
  guides(colour=guide_legend(reverse=TRUE))
```

[image]

**UPDATE:** Following up on my last comment, maybe it would help to visualize the regression surface for the model. It's a surface because b = f(a,c) is a function of two variables. The function is: `b = f(a,c) = -3.64 + 2.19*a + 3.00*c`, as shown above in the regression summary. This is the equation of a plane. Here's what it looks like when we plot it:

```
# Set up data grid for plotting
a=seq(1, 100, length.out=20)
c=seq(1, 100, length.out=20)
z = outer(a,c, FUN=function(a,c) -3.64 + 2.19*a + 3.00*c)

# Plot regression surface: b = f(a,c) = -3.64 + 2.19*a + 3.00*c
mat=persp(a, c, z, ylim=c(0,100), theta=35, phi=20, zlab="b", border="grey30")

# Add red lines of constant c
lapply(c(5,20,80,95), function(c_val) {
  lines(trans3d(x=a, y=c_val, z=-3.64 + 2.19*a + 3.00*c_val, pmat=mat), 
        col="red", lwd=2, lty="12")
```

Note in the plot below that each red line has a constant value of `c`. Only `a` varies. This is what the plot we made with `ggplot` becomes when you expand it into the 3rd dimension.

[image]

In fact, you can perhaps see this more easily if we rotate the 3D plot so that we are looking in the direction of the `c` axis (and perpendicular to the `a` axis) and reduce the perspective effect a bit. Compare the plot below with the one we made with ggplot:

```
# Plot regression surface: b = f(a,c) = -3.64 + 2.19*a + 3.00*c
mat=persp(a, c, z, ylim=c(0,100), theta=0, phi=0, zlab="b", border="grey30", d=5)

# Add red lines of constant c
lapply(c(5,20,80,95), function(c_val) {
  lines(trans3d(x=a, y=c_val, z=-3.64 + 2.19*a + 3.00*c_val, pmat=mat), 
        col="red", lwd=2, lty="12")
})
```

[image]

Comment: looks somewhat similar to mine, although it is numeric in my script.
Would it be possible to approximate a function for the family of curves of the geom_smooth lines, if so, how? In my df they are more similar (I removed a lot data to keep it small enough to post it)

Comment: What do you mean by "approximate a function for the family of curves of the geom_smooth lines." Do you mean you want the parameters for each of the regression lines?

Comment: no, I am looking for a function `y(x,k)` which approximates the **family of functions** of all regression lines

Comment: sorry I'm not a native English speaker. Simply looking for a function (obviously only possible with an approximative approach) which represents all regression lines (`x = a; y = b`) dependent of `c`. With this model I want to predict the regression line for a new `c`

Comment: No problem. I'd be pretty excited if I knew another language as well (or even half as well) as you obviously know English!

Comment: As far as a regression function, if `a`,`b`, and `c` are all numeric (as your gpplot code implies), then the most basic regression function would be `lm(b ~ a + c, data=Health)`. From that you can predict `b` for any values of `a` and `c`. Note however, that this will in general be different from the regression functions you get if you repeatedly run `lm(b ~ a)` for various fixed values of `c`.

Comment: But with this model I cant predict the line for single `c` values? I'm looking for a fixed function `b(a,c)`. so obviously the slope and intersect should somehow be dependent of `c`? e.g. I input `c = 80`, I need the function to return the approximated regression line `(a,b)` (based on `data = Health`). Or simply: a method which outputs for a random `c`(e.g. `c = 20`) the slope and intersect of the approximated regression line (based on the available `df`)

Comment: So the R code should return a function/formula (e.g. `y = x(2+c-3c^2) + 2*c`) where I input a random `c` (e.g. `c = 2` and get as output the function of the  specific regression line (e.g. `y = -10*x  + 4`). The function/formula which returns this new/specific regresion function should be approximated, based on the provided dataframe. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I created data with a particular functional form. In your real data you're trying to discover the appropriate function that relates `b` to `a` and `c`. Assuming a linear model, you run `m1 = lm(...)` to discover that function. In other words, `m1` (the object returned by `lm`) is the "function" that R returns. Then you use `predict` to get predictions for `b` given the model `m1` and input values for `a` and `c`.

Comment: Ok thanks for that, seems great so far. The only thing I am concerned is that all regression lines have the same slope. When I look at the original df and pull some regression lines for 5 `c`values, the slope differs very much. It almost seems like all regression lines are pivoting around a point. Is there any way to achieve this in R, to predict the **slope as well as the intersect** based on available data for a new `c`?

Comment: The only way to get different slopes is by adding interactions to the regression model. With only two variables, there's only one possible interaction: `lm(b ~ a*c, data=Health)`. In your case, I think you may be getting different slopes because ggplot is calculating a separate model `lm(b ~ a)` for each value of `c`, rather than a model including both variables. As a result, the slope for `a` is not constrained to be the same for each value of `c`. (FYI, it's "y-intercept" rather than "y-intersect".)

Comment: Is there no way that R looks at different regression lines (or `c's? and then approximates a formula of a new regression line  for any `c`? This would really help me, because `lm(b ~ a*c)` is also far away.

Comment: The coefficients of the model `m1` give you the regression function. The equation is `b = -3.64 + 2.19*a + 3.00*c`. This equation (which is what `predict` is using) gives you the modeled value of `b` for any values of `a` and `c` you choose to put into the equation. This regression equation is actually a regression "surface", because there a two predictor variables (`a` and `c`) involved. When you choose a particular value of `c` and create a regression line for `b` vs. `a`, you're looking at one particular line (a line of constant `c`) along that surface.